# Set background color for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibackgroundcolor

I have a problem when setting the background color for a UIView. What I am doing is:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

but I am getting a black background color as shown below:

[image: Incorrect Background Color - Illustrated]

If I change the background to any another color it works. Any ideas about this ?

Comment: What color do you expect to see under the view?

Comment: How can you see transparent?

Comment: Well... How would you describe that? You won't see the CPU and the battery inside the phone...

Comment: lol... now I know what I was asking is making nonsense now......

Comment: +1 because I'm not understanding why you are getting down-voted... I don't think it's right for you to lose reputation for asking for help on something you didn't fully understand at first.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: i agreed but it is their right to downvote. Im satisfied because now I learnt from my mistake..

Comment: This question just made my day :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view is working as intended.  You are setting it to use a clear background color, which means exactly as it is named, clear, and you will see color and possibly other UI elements underneath your view.  Think of it as placing clear plastic wrap (the view) on top of colored construction paper (the super view).  If you wish to find where the black color is coming from, I would start with your root controller's view.